# JavaScript Use a second thread to check for a date

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, date, asynchronous

I was trying to make a function, which compares 2 dates, run every 100ms. Since it is kinda bad to run it in the same thread, i wanted to make it run in a second thread so i can do other stuff at the same time. I am using node v16.7.0 btw.

```
function dateCompare(d1, d2){
    if(d1 <= d2){
        // Do some json config editing, already got that down dont worry
    }
}
```

I want to make this function run aside of the other code that i have below that (its listening for events if you are curious).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you asking how to implement threading? Also, please share whatever you have tried so far so we can help identify what isn't working.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for this ? - https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_threads

Comment: If you're using terms like "it is kinda bad" we can't understand what you mean. Why do you think it is bad?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is basically like in java when you create a thread that runs every x second. I wanted to implement this in javascript but i dont know what or how!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) doesn't block the main JS thread while waiting, nor does [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: It also doesn't run at exactly the specified interval, which might be an issue (or not). If it is, sequential calls of *setTimeout* based on a time difference from an epoch (or just next whole second) might be a better option. :-)